# Why is else triggering in this if else statement?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement

So I have this method in vue which changes the darkMode variable onclick,

What I don't understand is why it always triggers the if part and then also triggers the else part

```
data(){
    return{
      darkMode:false,
    }
  },
methods:{
darkModeToggle(){
  if(this.darkMode == false)
  {
    console.log("should be dark")
    this.darkMode = true
  }
  else(this.darkMode == true)
  {
    console.log("should be light")
    this.darkMode = false
  }
}
}
```

expected output is first click = "should be dark" then second click = "should be light"
However it is triggering twice on each click and outputting =
"should be dark" and
"should be light"

I know it works correctly with "else if" I just don't understand why it doesn't work this way.

Comment: `else(this.darkMode == true)` typo

Comment: Oh I put a condition in else gotta go sleep

Comment: You can't put a condition after `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple

else cannot have conditions in it
They should be like this

```
if(condition) {
} else {
}
```

if you want to get your desired output use else if
It should look like this

```
if(condition) {
} else if(another_condition) {
}
```